# Calculating total bytes of memory needed with macro in MASM

Tags: masm32

I have the following problem:

A program requires 2048 bytes (data and executable code). A macro is added that will require 48 bits of memory, and will need to be used 30 times.

How many bytes will the entire program require?

So, I thought it would be 2048 + 48 + (30 * 48). My rational is that you need the extra 48 for the declaration of the macro. But, the answer turns out to be 2048 + (30 * 48).

I'm wondering how come we don't count the declaration of the macro in the total bytes?

Thanks

Comment: The macro definition itself is just part of the source code, not the program code - only the *expansion* of the macro and its subsequent assembly into object code contribute to the size of the executable.